# java error: cannot find symbol EqualsUtil.areEqual

Tags: java

I am a beginner in Java.I am tying to implement some basic functionality in the class below.

```
/*Demonstrate the different data types in java*/
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class TypeDemo implements java.io.Serializable
{
    static byte b1=50;             /*byte variable     8 bits : (-128 TO 127) */
    static short s1=10;            /*short variable   16 bits : (-32,768 TO 32,767) */
    static int i1=-555;            /*int variable     32 bits : (-2,147,483,648 to 2,147,483,647) */
    static long l1=100000;         /*long variable    64 bits : (-9,223,372,036,854,775,808 to 9,223,372,036,854,775,807) */
    static float f1 = 123.2f;      /*float variable   32 bits : (4.9e-324 to 1.8e+308) (Approximate) */
    static double d1 = 1.4512;     /*double variable  64 bits : (1.4e-045 to 3.4e+038) (Approximate) */
    static char ch1 = 'Y';         /*char variable    16 bits : (0 - 65,536) (Needed for Unicode) */
    static boolean b = false;      /*boolean variable  1 bit  : (true OR false ) */

    public static void display()
    {
        System.out.println("The value of different variables");
        System.out.println("byte      : " + "b1  = " +b1);
        System.out.println("short     : " + "s1  = " +s1);
        System.out.println("int       : " + "i1  = " +i1);
        System.out.println("long      : " + "l1  = " +l1);
        System.out.println("float     : " + "f1  = " +f1);
        System.out.println("double    : " + "d1  = " +d1);
        System.out.println("char      : " + "ch1 = " +ch1);
        System.out.println("boolean   : " + "b   = " +b);
    }

    public boolean equals(Object aThat)
    {
        /*check for self comparision*/
        if (this == aThat) return true;

        /* use instanceof instead of getClass here for two reasons
         * 1. if need be, it can match any supertype, and not just one class;
         * 2. it renders an explict check for "that == null" redundant, since
         *    it does the check for null already - "null instanceof [type]" always
         * 3. returns false. (See Effective Java by Joshua Bloch.)
        */
        if ( !(aThat instanceof TypeDemo) ) return false;

        /* 
         * Alternative to the above line :
         * if ( aThat == null || aThat.getClass() != this.getClass() ) return false;
         */

           /*cast to native object is now safe*/
         TypeDemo that = (TypeDemo)aThat;

        /*
         *now a proper field-by-field evaluation can be made
         */

        return  EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.b1, that.b1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.s1, that.s1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.i1, that.i1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.l1, that.l1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.f1, that.f1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.d1, that.d1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.ch1,that.ch1) &&
                EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.b, that.b);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
        display();
   }
}
```

I am trying to override `equals()` method to compare the object field by field.I am not even able to compile the program.

```
TypeDemo.java:55: error: cannot find symbol
    return  EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.b1, that.b1) &&
            ^
  symbol:   variable EqualsUtil
  location: class TypeDemo
TypeDemo.java:56: error: cannot find symbol
            EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.s1, that.s1) &&
            ^
  symbol:   variable EqualsUtil
  location: class TypeDemo
TypeDemo.java:57: error: cannot find symbol
            EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.i1, that.i1) &&
            ^
  symbol:   variable EqualsUtil
  location: class TypeDemo
TypeDemo.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
            EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.l1, that.l1) &&
            ^
  symbol:   variable EqualsUtil
  location: class TypeDemo
TypeDemo.java:59: error: cannot find symbol
            EqualsUtil.areEqual(this.f1, that.f1) &&
```

I have imported `java.util.*` still it doesn't seem to be able to find `EqualsUtil`.

Comment: There is no `EqualsUtil` class in `java.util` package. You need to check the docs for `EqualsUtil` for necessary imports/references. P.S. Please, post only relevant code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `EqualsUtil` is not a part of Java Library (java.util.*)
If you see [this](http://www.javapractices.com/apps/stocksmonitor/javadoc/hirondelle/stocks/util/EqualsUtil.html)

Secondly, when you need to override the equals method you also have to override the hashcode
Refer below example

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
     if (obj == this){
        return true;
    }
    if (obj == null || obj.getClass() != this.getClass()){
        return false;
    }

    Person guest = (Person) obj;
    return id == guest.id
             &&(firstName == guest.firstName
                 || (firstName != null && firstName.equals(guest.getFirstName())))
             &&(lastName == guest.lastName
                 || (lastName != null && lastName .equals(guest.getLastName())));
}

@Override
public int hashCode(){
    final int prime = 31;
     int result = 1;
    result = prime * result
            + ((firstName == null) ? 0 : firstName.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + id;
     result = prime * result
            + ((lastName == null)? 0 : lastName.hashCode());
    return result;
 }
```

P.S. Example credit to [Javarevisited site](http://javarevisited.blogspot.co.uk/2011/02/how-to-write-equals-method-in-java.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to compare two objects for equality, you can simply override `equals` method for that object. and compare using

```
  yourOneObject.equals(yourAnotherObject);
```

**If you are overriding equals, then override hashcode also**

You can find a very good tutorial here.
http://www.thejavageek.com/2013/06/28/significance-of-equals-and-hashcode/